# Data table row click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am pulling data from a database using coldfusion into a dataTable and I would like that when I click on a row in the datatable and event is fired which so that the details of that row can be displayed in divs on the same page.

Below is the code I am using but it is not working, I would appreciate it if someone could give me an example that works

I get the following error message:

> Error - Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();

            $('#datatable-buttons tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

                var data = table.row( this ).data();
                // alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
                alert("table click"+data[0]);
            } );
        } );
```

Comment: Would you be able to produce a fiddle which replicates your issue?

Comment: Try outputting the `data` in console. Also, make sure that the html inside the table is valid i.e., uneven tr/td.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try unbinding the event for your buttons before you re-assign them: just add the following line before the row click:

```
$('#datatable-buttons tbody').off('click');
```

So changed code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#datatable-buttons').DataTable();
    $('#datatable-buttons tbody').off('click');
    $('#datatable-buttons tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        // alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
        alert("table click"+data[0]);
    } );
});
```